# In javaScript during a while loop how do you make the program stop to get user input?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

So this is what i have, very simplified version of my code. So basically the 'userinput' function needs to know whether the user clicked on button 'run' or 'hit':

html code:

```
<button id="run">Run</button>
<button id="hit">Hit</button>
```

javascript code:

```
slaying = true;
while(slaying){
  //gets user input
  userinput();
  // continue with the rest of the while loop until slaying is true
}
```

How would you write userinput()??

Comment: This is completely impossible.  You should use events or promises.

Comment: Do not use a loop like that. Use events and event handlers.

Comment: not sure how to handle the while loop, but if you just use rAF or setInterval this isn't impossible.... BUT it isn't advised.

Comment: have a look on angular see events and promises.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using a function `"userInput()"` you can use events and perform the same steps as you would do inside `userInput()`

You can use the `onclick` event as,

```
<button id="run" onclick="run()">Run</button>
<button id="hit" onclick="hit()">Hit</button>
```

And write the below script for this as,

```
function run(){
    alert("You pressed Run");
    //Steps to follow when Run is pressed.
}
function hit(){
    alert("You pressed Hit");
    //Steps to follow when Hit is pressed.
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5z2muwbf/1/)

Comment: OP doesn't tag jQuery and doesn't hint at using it. This code would require they include an external library to work.

Answer (score -4):

You can use

```
var response = prompt("Question ?", "Default answer");
```